# SQL query for output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables T1 with columns Id. It has 5 values

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table T2 has 3 columns WeekNo, Id (same as first table) and count and the data is like:

```
40 1 10
40 2 11
41 1 13
41 2 12
41 3 14
42 1 16
42 2 15
42 3 17
42 4 18
42 5 19
```

I am trying to write one query which will give output like:

```
40 1 10
40 2 11
40 3 0
40 4 0
40 5 0
41 1 13
41 2 12
41 3 14
41 4 0
41 5 0
42 1 16
42 2 15..
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a partitioned outer join:

```sql
SELECT t2.weekno,
       t1.id,
       COALESCE( t2.cnt, 0 ) AS cnt
FROM   T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
       PARTITION BY ( T2.weekno )
       ON (T1.id = T2.id);
```

outputs:

> ```
> WEEKNO | ID | CNT
> -----: | -: | --:
>     40 |  1 |  10
>     40 |  2 |  11
>     40 |  3 |   0
>     40 |  4 |   0
>     40 |  5 |   0
>     41 |  1 |  13
>     41 |  2 |  12
>     41 |  3 |  14
>     41 |  4 |   0
>     41 |  5 |   0
>     42 |  1 |  16
>     42 |  2 |  15
>     42 |  3 |  17
>     42 |  4 |  18
>     42 |  5 |  19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1b8052e13698ac01ac87609d591d48e7)*

Comment: Thank you. It works, i did not know about the partition by clause, will read on it.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you would generate the rows and then `left join` the values:

```
select w.weekno, t1.id, coalesce(t2.cnt, 0)
from (select distinct weekno from t2) w cross join
     t1 left join
     t2
     on t2.weekno = w.weekno and t2.id = t.id;
```

I assume the `partition by` clause has some superior performance compared to this.  It is an Oracle-only feature.